# how do I tell nginx to serve content_type as the requested file extension?

Tags: nginx, mime-types, content-type

I'm using nginx to serve files and when requested css files they are returned with content_type of text/plain which prevent them to be parsed as css in the browser.

I saw I can use a mime.types file to set the content type of files, but I don't want to add a file type each time I discover a problem

Is there any way to add a configuration that when asking a file type then the content_type will be the same as the extension of the requested file?

Comment: Your Nginx distribution should already include a `mime.types` file in the `.../etc/nginx` directory that includes many common mime types and their file extension. That file should be included at the top of your main Nginx configuration file.

Comment: but what if there's a new file extension that is not written there, if the one that is adding the new file isn't aware that he needs to add it to the nginx conf it will be very confusing when developing...
I just want it to set the content type to be the file extension

Comment: @ShayMualem You can add any custom type/extension using [`types`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#types) directive, however it seems that you just don't include default `mime.types` file to your nginx configuration.

Comment: I know, I'm asking if I can have nginx to set content_type by the extension of the requested file and not need to mime.types